# Javascript array value changes automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got one peculiar problem while working on with javascript. I have a temporary variable where I had stored a value while loading the page. Then I had to perform some filtering of data for some events, so I had assigned it to another variable and performed the filter like this:

```
var myVar = tempVar;
```

`myVar` is a new variable and initially `tempvar` has two array elements. After filtering I will be assigning the value to `myVar`. The strange thing occurs now. While `myVar` value changes, automatically `tempVar` value also changes. Do anyone know why this happens? If so can you tell me how to assign the variable value to another variable and perform operation without changing the variable's value?

Comment: these information is not enough, please share your code

Comment: post your code. many things are not clear unless you post your code here

Comment: You have to create a copy of the value hold in `tempVar`. How to do this exactly depends on the "type" of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, myVar = tempVar simply matches the object references to each other so they share the same object.

If you wish to clone an object using jQuery, you can use the jQuery extend option

```
var myVar = jQuery.extend(false, {}, tempVar);  // shallow Copy
var myVar = jQuery.extend(true, {}, tempVar);   // deep Copy
```

If your definition of objectToCopy was

```
var tempVar= {
   var item1 = 1;
   var item2 = 2;
   var deeperItem = {
        var item3 = 3
   }
}
```

A shallow copy would clone the first layer of data into the myVar .

Any changes to the tempVar item1,item2 would be independent of the myVar item1,item2.

However, any nested objects (like deeperItem), would still be linked, so myVar .deeperItem.item3 = 'New Value' would also set myVar .deeperItem.item3

If you want a full clone using jQuery, use the second method, which does a deep copy so its a completely seperate object.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 2):

This is because your are creating a reference to the array in the new variable, not copying it. Therefore both `myVar` and `tempVar` are pointing to the same variable.

To clone an array use `slice(0)`:

```
var myVar = tempVar.slice(0);
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a5hx/)

Comment: tempVar contains a array object.Now when i put slice(0) it throws an error like this "undefined is not a function"

Comment: @user2078883: If you get that error then you are not working with an array, like you claimed.